# When is class side initialize sent?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I am curious about when the class side initialize messages are sent in Smalltalk (Pharo and Squeak particularly). Is there any specified order? Is it at least safe to assume all other classes packaged with it have already been loaded and compiled, or does the system eagerly initialize (send initialize before even finishing loading and compiling the other classes)?

Answer (score 4):

The class-side `initialize` is never sent by the system. During development you do it manually (which is why many of these methods have a `"self initialize"` comment.

When exporting code of a class into a changeset, the exporter puts a send of `initialize` at the very end, so it gets executed when the class is loaded into another system.

This behavior is mimicked by Monticello. When loading a class for the first time, or when the code of the `initialize` method was changed, it is executed. That is because conceptually MC builds a changeset on-the-fly containing the difference of what is in the image already and what the package to be loaded contains. If that diff includes a class-side `initialize` method, it will be executed when loading that package version.

Answer (score 3):

As you asked about loading and compiling, I'm assuming you mean when loading code...

When loading a package or changeset, class-side #initialize methods are called after all code is installed [(1)](http://forum.world.st/initialize-and-MC-tp54954p54955.html). While you can not count on a specific order, you can assume that all classes and methods from that package are loaded.

As Bert pointed out, if you were not loading but *implementing* class-side #initialize, you'd have to send the message yourself.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is the case in general. For instance, Monticello does the post load `#initialize` explicitly, which means its not being handled by any "internal" loading logic. Depending on how you load your code `#initialize` may *never* be sent (although for most people this is unlikely to be the case).

Answer (score 1):

One way to know for sure, is to test it yourself. Smalltalk systems make this kind of thing a little more approachable than many other systems. Just define a your own `MyTestClass`, and then implement your own *class side* (that's important) `initialize` message so that you can discover for yourself when it fires, how often it fires, etc.

```
initialize
    Transcript show: 'i have been INITIALIZED!!! Muwahahahah!!!'
```

Make sure it works by opening a `Transcript` and running

```
MyTestClass initialize
```

from a `Workspace`. Now you can play with filing it out and back in, Monticello loading, whatever and when it runs.